# Get a Map With All the song on the Device and their Paths in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Ok, this question is pretty straightforward, how can I get all the Songs on a device (or If on the entire device is not possible at least in one folder, for example, the music one) in a map containing all the songs with their respective path in something like this:

```
var song= {
  // Key:    Value
  'title': 'All Star',
  'author': 'Smash Mouth', //Optional but would like to get this too
  'album': 'All Star', //Optional but would like to get this too
  'path': 'storage/emulated/0/Music'

};
```

How Could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Android has a mediaplayer class, which scans all media files and generates corresponding database information when booting and plugging and unplugging sd cards. You can get information about music files in the following way.

```
private List<SingListBean> getAllSing(Context context) {
    int flag = 1;
    List<SingListBean> listBeans = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query
            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String singName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
        String singAlbum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
        Long _size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE));
        int duration = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
        String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
        listBeans.add(new SingListBean(flag++, singName, singAlbum, _size, duration, url));
    }
    return listBeans;
}
```

Comment: It does not help, the question was how to do it in flutter.